# How to add a Standard User record to an object programmatically?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, user, lightning-duallistbox

So my question is that I have bunch of standard users that I want to insert into my custom object i.e Training Plan. And I want to do it programmatically, so is there a way to achieve it.

What I have done till now is that I have used duel-list-box and I have added some users in available section of duel list box. And now I want to select some users and add them to a certain training plan.

How do i proceed now??

Heres the LWC bundle:

**userTrainee.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-dual-listbox name="languages"
                            label="Select Languages"
                            source-label="Available"
                            selected-label="Selected"
                            field-level-help="Select trainees"
                            options={options}
                            onchange={handleChange}></lightning-dual-listbox>
    <div class="slds-box" >
        <p>Selected values are: {selected}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

**userTrainee.js**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getTrainee from '@salesforce/apex/Trainees.getTrainee';
import MailingPostalCode from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingPostalCode';

export default class UserTrainee extends LightningElement {
    selected = [];

    @wire(getTrainee)
    eventArr;      

    get options() {
        let result = [];

        // this eventsArr.data is an array, 
        // so we need to be more speecific to fetch actual values ie. Id, name in this case
        if(this.eventArr.data){           
            this.eventArr.data.forEach(u =>{
                result.push({label:u.Name , value:u.Id});
            }); 
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));    // to verify the result 
        return result;
        // return [
        //     { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
        //     { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
        //     { label: 'Hindi', value: 'es' },
        //     { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
        //     { label: 'Italian', value: 'it' },
        //     { label: 'Japanese', value: 'ja' },
        // ];
    }

    get selected() {
        if (this.selected.length) return this.selected;
        else return 'none';
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.selected = e.detail.value;        // e.detail.value is just record id
        console.log(e.detail.value);
    }
}
```

**ApexController.cls**

```
public with sharing class Trainees {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<User> getTrainee(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name from User];
    }
}
```

And then I have `Training Plan` object where i want the these users to. How do i proceeed??
Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in the training plan object, you need to create a lookup to user object.

in lwc, you will pass the selected user list  and training plan id (if already exists)  to an apex method  which will create/update (upsert)   training plan  for each selected user.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do following things:

1. There are two things to consider (i) User who are not in Trainee Plan and (ii) User who are already in Trainee plan.

You need to separate those first. For this I have created a `Is_Trainee__c` checkbox on User to filter out already selected user.

below is the code example:

Apex :

```
public with sharing class Trainees {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<User> getTrainee(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name,Is_Trainee__c from User WHERE IsActive=true /*AND (add your profile or role filter here) */];//example : Role.Name='Standard User' / Profile.Name='Standard User'
    }
 }
```

Html:

```
<lightning-dual-listbox name="Trainee Plan"
                        label="Select Trainee"
                        source-label="Available"
                        selected-label="Selected"
                        field-level-help="This is a dual listbox"
                        options={options}
                        value={values}></lightning-dual-listbox>
```

Js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getTrainee from '@salesforce/apex/Trainees.getTrainee';
import addTrainee from '@salesforce/apex/Trainees.addTrainee';
export default class UserTrainee extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedUsers = [];
    @track options = [];
    @track values = [];
    error;

    @wire(getTrainee)
    eventArr({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            var users = data;
            for (var i in users) {
                if (users[i].Is_Trainee__c) {
                    this.values.push(users[i].Id);
                }
                this.options.push({
                    label: users[i].Name,
                    value: users[i].Id
                });
            }
            this.selectedUsers = this.values;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

2. Now while selecting the new trainee you need to separate User who are already in  Trainee Plan with the User you are selecting for new Trainee Plan. For this I have used `selectedUsers` to filter out new Trainee with old trainee and at last you need to update `Is_Trainee__c` checkbox on User.

Below is the code example:

Js:

```
handleChange(e) {
        var newTrainee = [];
        var userTrainee = [];
        this.selectedUsers = e.detail.value; // e.detail.value is just record id
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedUsers));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.values));
        for (var i in this.selectedUsers) {
            var isTrainee = false;
            for (var j in this.values) {
                if (this.values[i] === this.selectedUsers[i]) {
                    isTrainee = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isTrainee) {
                newTrainee.push({
                    User__c: this.selectedUsers[i]
                });
                userTrainee.push({
                    Id: this.selectedUsers[i],
                    Is_Trainee__c: true
                });
            }
        }

        if (newTrainee.length > 0 && userTrainee.length > 0) {
            addTrainee({ trainees: JSON.stringify(newTrainee), users: JSON.stringify(userTrainee) })
                .then((response) => {
                    for (var i in newTrainee) {
                        this.values.push(newTrainee[i].User__c)
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {

                })
        }
    }
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void addTrainee(String trainees, String users){
        List<Trainee__c> newTrainees =(List<Trainee__c>) System.JSON.deserialize(trainees, List<Trainee__c>.Class);
        List<User> updateUsers =(List<User>) System.JSON.deserialize(users, List<User>.Class);
        if(!newTrainees.isEmpty()){
            insert newTrainees;
        }
        if(!updateUsers.isEmpty()){
            update updateUsers;
        }
    }
```

Note: You can modified the logic as per your requirement. Here I have created a checkbox on User object but if your business requirement doesn't allow you to create any field then you can query all the trainee and compare with user to separate User who are already in Trainee plan.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot Shagun, I will try and and will ask you if I get stuck at a point if you dont mind.

Comment: Sure, go ahead :)